# I need to access data in the object message: "{'data':{'status':'active'}}". it throws error while access while stringfy

Tags: reactjs, json

```
message: "{'data':{'status':'active'}}"
```

this is my object i need to access data in the json.i unable to access this.if i tried to access the data, it gives json access error.

Answer (score 1):

JSON.parse() does not allow single quotes.

So if you want to parse "{'data':{'status':'active'}}" then you have to first replace all the single quotes with double quotes

```
const object = { message: "{'data':{'status':'active'}}"} 
const parsedObject = JSON.parse(object.message.replaceAll("'", '"'))
console.log(parsedObject)
```

[JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#json.parse_does_not_allow_single_quotes)